Search a pattern from one file and replace next line with another pattern in another file in Shell script
I have two files file test.txt and ref.txt. I want to read ref.txt which has comma seperated 3 values. I want to match pattern in test.txt with first value in ref.txt, if found replace next line if matching with Value2 with value3 from ref.txt
 $cat test.txt
[first]
Database=xxx
HostName=yyy

[second]
Database=aaa
HostName=bbb


$ cat ref.txt (case sensitive values)
XxX,Yyy,ZZz
aaa,Bbb,Ccc

Here is my code
cat code.sh
while read line;
do
Name=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`;
Source=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`;
Dest=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $3}'`;
echo $Name
echo $Source
echo $Dest
sed -ri '/$Name/I { n; s/$Source/$Dest/I }' test.txt
done < ref.txt

it does not generate desired output. please help , what is worng ?
The desired out put is to modify test.txt in place like:
[first]
Database=xxx
HostName=zzz
[second]
Database=aaa
HostName=ccc

i,e the hostname value need to be replaced.

In sed you do not get shell variables expanded because you use single quotes '

"it does not generate desired output" – What does it generate then? And more importantly: what is the exact desired output? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Edited the question with desired output.

Did you mean cat ref.txt #(case sensitive values)? In other words: was the thing in parentheses supposed to be a comment? And did the comment mean what it says? If so, then your desired output is not consistent with the rest (bbb is not Bbb etc.).
